Вопрос по CSS таблицы, а конкретнее про объединённые ячейки colspan
Всех приветствую, всем здравия!
Вот такой вопрос есть по CSS и таблице. Есть таблица простая в виде
<table class="table_class">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">General</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name TTX</strong></td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name TTX</strong></td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

В таблице есть несколько объединённых ячеек по горизонтали, вот таких
<td colspan="2">General</td>

Эдакие заглавия блоков характеристик, в них текст более жирный и чуть больше, так вот, есть ли возможность в CSS стилях прописать условие, что в этой объединённой ячейке с td colspan="2" будет определённый шрифт с определённым размером.
Сейчас я тупо присваиваю тексту в этих ячейках  тег. Сам пробовал в стилях прописать и так
.table_class td colspan 2 {
    font-size: 18px;

и так
.table_class td colspan {
    font-size: 18px;

Ничего не получилось. Существует ли возможность написать стиль на таблицу, что бы в этих ячейках с colspan прописывался свой стиль шрифта без добавление вручную в каждую такую ячейку h3?
С Уважением к сообществу.

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

Всё элементарно, Ватсон:


td[colspan="2"] {
  color: red;
}
<table class="table_class">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">General</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name TTX</strong></td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name TTX</strong></td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




А так просто на td с атрибутом colspan:


td[colspan] {
  color: red;
}
<table class="table_class">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">General</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name TTX</strong></td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name TTX</strong></td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Спасибо вам за помощь!!!

Галочку слева от ответа - тык)

Нажал галочку, извините я тут новичок и ещё не осознал как благодарить :)
